# python class initialize custom class referencing to existing list

Tags: python, list, class, inheritance

I have class MyList that inherits from list. When I pass instance of list ie. [0, 3, 5, 1] to MyList, how to construct MyList to avoid copy and have self have no-copy reference to other content.

I have tried with:

*`other.__class__ = MyList`* : gives **TypeError**

and with

*`super(MyList, cls).__new__(other)`* : gives **TypeError**

and with

*`super(MyList, other)`* : gives **TypeError**

lastly with

*`self[:] = other[:]`* : gives id(self) != id(other)

Also simple *MyList([0, 1, 3, 4])* would not solve problem when I do some operations in-place inside MyList.

```py
class MyList(list):
   def __new__(cls, other):
        other.__class__ = MyList
        return other
   # add bunch of methods that work inplace on list
   def merge(self,):
       pass
   def sort(self,):
       pass
   def find(self, x):
       pass
   def nextNonMember(self, x): 
       pass
```

Alternative way that I want to avoid is:

```py
class MyNotSoFancyList(object):
     def __init__(self, other):
         self.list = other
```

I expect to have this behavior:

```py
t = [0, 1, 3, 100, 20, 4]
o = MyList(t)
o.sort()
assert(t == o)
```

Question is probably not so trivial one for me when I dont know Python on "low" level. It seems its not possible. Thus I wanted to ask, maybe someone knows some trick xD.

**EDIT**

Until now there was one hint in message to be deleted. Need some time to digest it, so will keep it here:

@RobertGRZELKA I think I kinda got to a conclusion with myself that this simply can't be done. As when you create an object of the class, it instantiates a new list in memory and references it. So if want to reference another list, there is no point in the new object. Bottom line I believe you will have to have the reference as an attribute of the class, implement your methods, and then override the list methods you are going to use so that they work on the referenced list. Tell me when you read that and I will delete this answer – Tomerikoo 2 hours ago

Comment: You've already created a vanilla list instance, that's what `t` is. Why do you want to somehow convert that, after creation, into something else?

Comment: I want to avoid having extra member in class if all operations will be done on self.

Comment: so is Mylist and MyClass the same thing?

Comment: simply do `o = t`...

Comment: Why do you ever assign the list? Just do `t = MyClass([0, 1, 3, 100, 20, 4])`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am guessing this is the OP's way of MRE and the list `t` is probably coming from somewhere... This has a XY problem feel to it...

Comment: sorry I misspelled MyClass and MyList. There is not MyClass. Only MyList!

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
class MyList(list):
     def __init__(self,value):
             self.extend(value)
```

I dont really understand why you would want it unless you want to add more methods to the list object. but that should give you a list

```
t = [0, 1, 3, 100, 20, 4]
o = MyList(t)
o.sort()
t.sort()
assert(t==o)
```

Comment: This doesn't really work you know? I mean the `assert` obviously fail...

Comment: maybe thats because you sorted o and not t?

Comment: try again. Also sort t this time

Comment: That probably will work, but it just loses the point isn't it? I believe the intention of OP was to avoid that...

Comment: its not good this way, bcos its copy, I dont want to have copy, or shallow copy, but more like "pointer" thing

Comment: @RobertGRZELKA read about variables in Python. What you need is simply a variable referencing the list. something like `new_list = t`. No need for a class...

Comment: MyList is children class of list that inherits from list! So how to do that but for self = other inside class constructor?

Comment: @RobertGRZELKA I understand that! I am just saying it is not necessary... since you just want to reference the list with another variable... no class is needed at all

Comment: no, I want to have instance of MyList that data points to data of list